# JavaScript scss & CSS tv turn on off animation not working - need help to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scss-mixins

I found this javascript code from codepen, it is perfectly working in codepen console but when I try to open it on my computer it did not work out of codepen, even though I use jquery. but still not working. I also try to use it in jsfiddle but also not working in jsfiddle. and I also compile SCSS code CSS but it also not working too. but it is perfectly working in Codepen. The button perfectly switches on-off the TV.

[Here is the codepen link:](https://codepen.io/francescostella/pen/ONaWvZ)

[Here is the SCSS JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o5ms0dh/)

[Here is the CSS JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o5ms0dh/1/)

HTML Code:

```
<section class="screen">
  <div class="content">
    <!-- [FS] NOTE: This is can be treated also as normal web page and containg normal content -->
  </div>
</section>
<button id="switcher-tv">Turn on/off</button>
```

SCSS Code:

```
$color-text: #e1eef6;
$color-link: #ff5f2e;
$color-link-hover: #fcbe32;
$black: #111111;

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: $black;
}

a {
  color: $color-link;
  
  &:hover {
    color: $color-link-hover;
  }
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.screen {
  background-color: $color-text;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  content: " ";
  overflow: hidden;
  
    // Fallback for old browsers
  background: #16222A;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #16222A , #3A6073);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #16222A , #3A6073);
  
  background-size: cover;
  
  background-image: url(https://cldup.com/gn3s3Fg75t.gif);
  
   color: $color-text;
}
```

JS Code:

```
(function() {
  var SELECTOR_SCREEN_ELEMENT = '.screen';
  var SELECTOR_SWITCHER_TV = '#switcher-tv';
  
  var isTurnedOn = true;
  
  var timeline;
  
  function buildTimeline() {
    timeline = new TimelineMax({
      paused: true
    });
    
    timeline
    .to(SELECTOR_SCREEN_ELEMENT, .2, {
      width: '100vw',
      height: '2px',
      background: '#ffffff',
      ease: Power2.easeOut
    })
    .to(SELECTOR_SCREEN_ELEMENT, .2, {
      width: '0',
      height: '0',
      background: '#ffffff'
    });
  }
  
  function toggleSwitcherTV() {
    if (isTurnedOn) {
      timeline.restart();
    }
    
    if (!isTurnedOn) {
      timeline.reverse();
    }
    
    isTurnedOn = !isTurnedOn;
  }
  
  // Initialize
  $(document).ready(buildTimeline);
  
  // Bindings
  $(document).on('click', SELECTOR_SWITCHER_TV, function() {
    toggleSwitcherTV();
  });
})();
```

Compiled CSS Code:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #111111;
}
a {
  color: #ff5f2e;
}
a:hover {
  color: #fcbe32;
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.screen {
  background-color: #e1eef6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  content: " ";
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #16222A;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #16222A, #3A6073);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #16222A, #3A6073);
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://cldup.com/gn3s3Fg75t.gif);
  color: #e1eef6;
}
```

Comment: I tried out your js fiddle example. First yo haven't select jquery in js panel and second the browser console shows `TimelineMax() is not defined.`. Please fix it.

Comment: then how it is perfectly working in CodePen with same code? , i suggest you please modify the jsfiddle and give a working example.

Comment: I checked you codepen example and figured out three js libaries are added. These are jquery, lodash and timelinemax. jsfiddle cannot add all these extern libraries.

Comment: Just like @Reporter said, you surely haven't added any of the dependencies needed for this example to work. I would highly suggest going through some more basics & dev tools usage, 9 out of 10 times in these kind of scenarios, the problems are highlighted there, and you can continue with the more specific solution to your issues.
TL;DR: import/download/add jQuery, GSAP, lodash, preferably in those specific versions

Comment: Thanks for figure out the problem, the js libaries was not shown in my old browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a simple way, like add class when they click for turning on tv and also vise versa for turning off the tv. When the class add in the section put that CSS using that new class.

```js
$("#switcher-tv").click(function(){
  $(".screen").toggleClass("tvON");
});
```

```css
.screen.tvON{
  background-image: url(https://cldup.com/gn3s3Fg75t.gif);
}
```